# defining multiple variables with one `var` keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, var

I have a line in my source code written by someone else:

```
var campaignLimits = 10, campaignsArray = new Array();
```

I just wanted to know, whether `campaignsArray` here becomes global variable, or the `var` applies to `campaignsArray` as well?

Comment: is it written inside a function ?

Comment: `var campaignLimits = 10, campaignsArray = new Array();` is the same as `var campaignLimits = 10; var campaignsArray = new Array();`. Whether they're global or not will depend on the scope where they're defined.

Comment: the second one. for testing you can put it in a function and console.log that variable outside of that function.

Comment: var applies to campaignsArray as well. It's supported by Douglas Crockford, you may find some articles on this choice : http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/single-var-pattern/ and its critic http://danhough.com/blog/single-var-pattern-rant/

Comment: Both `campaignLimits` and `campaignArrays` become a variable within a current scope. If you declare it in a global scope, they will both become global variables.

Comment: @SharathBangera yes, it is inside a function.

Comment: (function() { var campaignLimits = 10, campaignsArray = new Array(); })(); run this in your console, its not global as it is inside a function

Comment: @phoa Yes, I actually just wanted to know if it's equivalent to adding a var before the second variable declaration. You can add it as an answer.

Comment: It behaves exactly as the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) says it does. In any case, this would be trivial to test in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not used any programming pattern, If its written inside a function then its not global.

```
(function() { var campaignLimits = 10, campaignsArray = new Array(); })();
```

as @phoa commented it is same as

```
(function() { var campaignLimits = 10; var campaignsArray = new Array(); })();
```

Try it in your console and see whether you will be able to access campaignsArray.

Comment: What do you mean by "assuming you have not used any programming pattern"?